# Lua Command Enable/Disable

Tags: lua, command

I am looking to try and enable/disable the ability to use `!commands` (commands in this game (Command and Conquer: Renegade) are always prefixed with a `!`) depending on whether a text file dictates a user is allowed to use it or not. I am looking for the code to be in Lua, for compatibility and integration. For example:

Harry1 is allowed to use `!spectate`
Harry2 is not allowed to use `!spectate`

However, this could be for an infinite number of users, as each can select a maximum of 3 "options", and the rest of these "options" are not allowed to be accessible to a user who has not picked it as one of their 3. For example:

Harry1 chose `!spectate`, `!cookie`, `!pizza`
Harry2 chose `!cookie`, `!icecream`, `!chocolate`

Thus, Harry1 would not be able to use `!icecream` or `!chocolate` and Harry2 could not use `!spectate` or `!pizza`.

Getting a player ID is used by `Get_Player_ID(pID)`.

Comment: Is there a restriction for the file type or can you choose it freely?

Comment: Sorry, I should have stated that in the OP: I wish for it to be in lua so it can be integrated into existing code... I lack any form of knowledge of C++, which would be the only alternative.

Answer (score 0):

It's best to design the layout of the data first. As Lua is designed to be also a data description language, it's natural to use the native syntax, so the choices file would look like this:

```
user {
    name: "Harry1",
    choices: {["spectate"]=true, ["cookie"]=true, ["pizza"]=true},
}

user {
    name: "Harry2",
    choices: {["cookie"]=true, ["icecream"]=true, ["chocolate"]=true},
}
```

Then, in the code, you can do the following:

```
users = {}

function user_docommand(user, command)
    if users[user].choices[command] == true do
        --- do the command
    end
end

do
    function user(u)
        if users[u.name] == nil then
             users[u.name] = {}
        end
        users[u.name].choices = u.choices
    end
    --- perharps use a safer function than dofile here
    dofile("choices.lua")
end
```

See also [10.1 - Data Description from PIL 1st edition](http://www.lua.org/pil/10.1.html)

Comment: Thanks for your assistance! However, I am a total newb to things like this, and I would like to know: Where do I put the specific commands in the second piece of code you showed me? :s Also, I'm not sure what the aim of the first part of code is, essentially, the user will be the one choosing the commands... Thanks for your help so far though!

Comment: @HarryLudlow the first piece would be the configuration file - it can be written by the program too, though. And as for the second part, it shows just a bit of the principle for implementing the privilege functionality, it's far from complete - complete implementation depends on the already existing code and is too specific for this site.

Comment: I see, but how would one go about making the program write the config file? I have tried tangling with write/readini stuff before, to no avail :/ Do you have any links which could provide a simplistic outlook on creation of such files?

Comment: If you want to use `dofile` with BibTex-like definitions as seen in this example, you cannot have the function `user` as a `local`, because it won't be seen by the config file.